# Stdout output not remotely accessible when connecting to a Jupyter notebook over ssh

Tags: python, ssh, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, gnu-screen

My current workflow with Jupyter notebooks is to have a notebook server running on machine X, inside a `screen` session:

```
screen -S jupyter
jupyter notebook
```

I then connect with my notebook server via `ssh` from laptop Y:

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:8888:localhost:8888 [user]@[server]
```

What I want is to be able to start, disconnect and regularly check in on calculations on machine X from Y. I found running Jupyter from a screen session worked better when starting a calculation from laptop Y. At least the currently executing cell finishes even if the ssh connection is lost. But any print statements or `matplotlib` plots produced when I am disconnected does not show in the notebook once I connect again. I guess `stdout` may be sending things only to the notebook if it's currently opened?

EDIT: the problem is not related to `screen` at all, it is a problem with jupyter browser notebooks in general:

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1647

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/4140

Workarounds can be found in the discussion in the links above.